How to Update an Android App with a New Developer Account?
I had a Google Play developer account that was closed due to inactivity. Now, I'm considering creating the same app under a new developer account.
If I use the same signing key and package name, will the app be recognized as an update for users who already have it installed?
If not, are there specific steps or important considerations when re-publishing the app under a new account?

As far as I know once the account is closed, existing apps' package name will be permanently tied to that account and nobody will be able to claim it again. Which means you won't be able to use same package name from another account

You’re asking a great question, and yes, the app’s signing key and package name play a critical role here. If you use the same signing key and package name as the original app, it will indeed be recognised as an update for users who already have it installed. However, you’ll need to ensure that your new Google Play developer account adheres to all of Google’s policies to avoid any issues during the re-publishing process. Another consideration is optimised performance, which is key to maintaining user retention, especially when transitioning an app. Users expect fast-loading and responsive experiences, and frameworks like Angular can be instrumental in achieving this. For a deeper dive into its relevance, check out is angular dead, which explores how modern tools remain vital for top-tier development. Wishing you success with your app relaunch!
